# regex php parse zip code and remove from string

Tags: php, regex, zipcode

I have an app where I am parsing addresses and have been trying to implement the following regex expression to grab a US zip code from an address.  once I grab it, I want to remove the zip code from the address string as the zipcode is interfering with grabbing the phone number.  However, the following is not grabbing the zipcode.

```
$string = "John Doe 1234 Main Street Peoria, IL 60601 (555) 555-5555";
function extract_zipcode_from($string){
  preg_match_all("/\b[A-Z]{2}\s+\d{5}(-\d{4})?\b/", $string, $matches);
  return $matches[0];
}
$zip = extract_zipcode_from($string);
$zip = print_r(implode("\n", $zip),true);
$string = str_ireplace($zip,"",$string);
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `preg_replace()` to remove it. The manual search and str_replace is unneeded.

Comment: The error in your code is that you are not wrapping the zip code in parentheses to capture them. `(\d{5}(-\d{4})?)` - once you get that, look at what you have in the matches array. Then, having honed your regular expression, use preg_replace() instead as mario suggests.

Comment: you mean preg_match_all("/\b[A-Z]{2}\s+(\d{5})(-\d{4})?)\b/", $string, $matches);

Comment: I was able to get following that I found on another website to work.  Not sure why pregreplace is better than str_replace.  From what I read str_ireplace is plenty fast: $zip_pattern = "/\d{5}/";
$str = "Mission Viejo, CA 92692";
preg_match($zip_pattern,$str,$regs);
$zip= $regs[0];$str = str_ireplace($zip,"",$str);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will give you phone and zip with out replacing anything .

**Assuming that Zip and phone will be always at the end of the string, Anything that comes after zip is a phone number.**

```
$string = "John Doe 1234 Main Street Peoria, IL 60601 (555) 555-5555";

preg_match("/(?P<zip>\d{5})(?P<phone>.*)$/",$string,$match);

echo "Zip : ".$match['zip'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Phone : ".$match['phone'];
```